# where can environment variables be USED in a kubernetes manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

Using the example to [set env variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) I can set them, but I cannot find documentation on where I can USE them in the manifest.  Replacing a literal value with an env variable for hostAliases IP gives an error:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
    - name: HOST_ALIAS_IP
      value: "127.0.0.1"      
  hostAliases:
  - ip: $(HOST_ALIAS_IP)
    hostnames:
    - "desktop"
```

> C:>kubectl apply -f envars.yaml
> The Pod "envar-demo" is invalid: spec.hostAliases.ip: Invalid value: "$(HOST_ALIAS_IP)": must be valid IP address

Comment: Templatizing manifests is typically the responsibility of Helm or Kustomize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use environment variables in the manifest. You can only make use of them inside the pod. They describe the environment of the pod, not the environment in which your manifest is parsed.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?  I understand the other solutions options (search/replace in yaml, implement Helm) but I try to leverage native functionality first.  I am trying to set a value that effects the environment of the pod, but if the parser does not support this, I will make a suggestion to kubernetes that they add this documentation.

Comment: I think the opposite is documented -- the Kubernetes documentation is typically quite thorough, and never suggests that pod manifests support any sort of variable interpolation.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer as stating it is not supported and it is not documented.  "Never suggesting" a feature in documentation is not the same as explicitly stating it is not supported.  Having it explicit saves lots of time (and avoids questions like this where I think I am doing something wrong.)